# AngularJS ui-grid import XLSX data best approach

Tags: xlsx, angular-ui-grid

What would be the best approach to import XLSX data to be displayed using an AngularJS ui-grid?

Is the js-xlsx parser a good choice for this, or are there other open source XLSX parser tools better suited for this task? In my case the XLSX data is very basic, nothing complicated, but I would like to preserve the style info as much as possible. I anticipate the the data grid will be less than 20 col x 1000 rows.

Or would it be better to use an alternative data grid, such as the Hansontable, instead of ui-grid? Would that be better suited for spreadsheet data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing data into the grid with js-xlsx should work fine. I've been able to get it working with my simple Open Office files so I would imagine you will be mostly OK.

Style info is another question, though. If you're wanting to maintain cell-specific backgrounds and such that could be more difficult. Can you share your specific use case that you want to handle?

For others who might be interested: once you've read a file into your browser and turned it into a workbook you can use `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json()` to easily dump the spreadsheet contents into a structure you can pass into your grid.  If you pass `{ header: 1 }` as an argument to that function it will return a simple array-of-arrays of the data. The first element in the array will be your header row if you have one. You can use that to create your column definitions.

If you want to see a working plunker check this one out: http://plnkr.co/edit/rYC3nd7undqJz2mr8Old?p=preview

And if you want a more in-depth tutorial I have this post explaining SheetJS  and the contents of the plunker: http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/

Comment: Thank you, this work as I wanted. Should be marked as anserd.

Comment: Can your solution be used with ui.grid.importer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.importer or should it be implemented independently to ui-grid-importer?